# JS - video.play() only play for some seconds then stops, no error in console

Tags: javascript, html

The play() function does not play the video till the end, the evcentlistener is closed and in console i have no error that could help me.

Here is the full version:
https://codepen.io/apistol/pen/LOgaWw?editors=1010

```
var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var fclick = document.getElementById("first-click");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector(".pause-button");

function addShowClass() {
  var element = document.getElementById("fclick");
  element.classList.add("display-inherit");
}

function vidPlay() {
  video.play();
}
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 5) {
    this.pause();
    addShowClass();
    this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", arguments.calee);
  }
});
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
})
```

Comment: `if(this.currentTime >= 5 ){ this.pause();` after 5sec you did pause the video

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var fclick = document.getElementById("first-click");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector(".pause-button");


function addShowClass() {
   var element = document.getElementById("fclick");
   element.classList.add("display-inherit");
}

function vidPlay() {
         video.play();
 }



video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {  
  if(this.currentTime >= 5.00 ){
      this.pause();
      addShowClass();
      this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", arguments.callee);
    }
});

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if(video.paused) {
    video.play();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }

})
```

There's nothing wrong with your attempt. You just had a typo:

You wrote

```
this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", arguments.calee);
```

But it should be

```
this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", arguments.callee);
```

(note the double l in callee)

This is why the removeEventListener could not remove the event. I don't know why it doesn't tell you that in the console...